# Installing nsight for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition, and when I try to install nsight i get the following information in the installation window

> Nsight for Visual Studio 2010 will not be installed
>    Requirement not met

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: I am not entirely certain, but I seem to remember that the Express edition of Visual Studio does not allow for the kind of plugin necessary. So I don't think it will work with that. If I can confirm this I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Nsight Visual Studio Edition requires Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 Professional (or higher) in order to allow for the deep level of integration with the IDE.